# Can my cycle-cut algorithm sample any DAG?

Tags: sampling, simulation, structural-equation-modeling, dag, causal-diagram

I am doing some computational simulations to validate a procedure involving structural equation models and causal inference. I wanted to sample from the possible space of DAGs on $n$ vertices. I can up with a simple algorithm:

> **Algorithm**
>
> Given $n$ and $p$.
>
> 1. Sample an adjacency matrix $A_{n \times n}$ with IID $a_{ij} \sim \text{binomial}(1,p)$.
> 2. Construct digraph data structure from adjacency matrix from $A$.
> 3. While the digraph is not a DAG:
>
> - Use depth-first search to find a cycle.
> - With uniform probability, delete an edge from the cycle.

I am pretty skeptical that this algorithm would uniformly sample DAGs, but looking at some visualized samples I didn't find that there was much of an (obvious to me) tendency among the DAGs.

But the main question is not uniformity, although of course that would be ideal in my case. Rather, I would like to know if this algorithm with greater than zero probability can (eventually) sample any given DAG with $n$ vertices where $p \in (0,1)$.

---

If it helps at all, I expect that $n \leq 100$ will usually be chosen. Here is a visual example of a SEM sampled using the algorithm.

[image]